# How to fill in the empty space in between images for volumetric imaging/ 3D reconstruction in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, imaging, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to create a 3D model of packed spherical beads with image slices. These images are of spherical beads with varying diameters, taken 0.0015 apart. The cube is 2.154x2.154x2.154. I was able to "stack" the images on top of each other and negate empty space to compile a model. I now have the issue of filling in the space in between the image slices in order to run simulations/evaluate the space unoccupied by spheres.

I tried using the matlab function interp3 but I'm having trouble applying it. I'm also unsure if this is the correct method to "fill in" or "complete" the spheres. The following code only uses every third image within the range of the first 43 out of 1408 images.

[isometric view of stacked images - height 0.0643](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKHQ1.jpg)

[Side view of images stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u78Ws.jpg)

```
for i = 1:3:43 %height - 0.0643 out of 2.154
    filename = ['10000_test_packing_' sprintf('%0.0f',i) '.tif'];
    temp=double(imread(filename));
    image(:,:,i) = .5*(temp(:,:,1)==1) +(temp(:,:,2)==0) + 2*(temp(:,:,3)==0);
end

volumeViewer(image)

%% "Filling in the Spheres"
%Interpolation using interp3?

[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(0:656, 0:875, 0:20);
[x, y, z] = meshgrid(0:656, 0:875, 0:.24:20);
test = interp3(X, Y, Z, image(:,:,1), x, y, z, 'cubic');
```

The first section of the code only stacks the images but does not make it possible to evaluate the volume of "empty space" within the cube. This is because the slices hold no volume and within the space between images, there is nothing.

I need to find a way to solidify the spheres so that there is no space in between slices and that the spheres are complete.

Comment: You should read in your slices without leaving the space in between, then you can interpolate: `image(:,:,(i+2)/3) = ...` and then probably something like `test = interp3(0:656, 0:875, 0:20, image(:,:,1), 0:656, 0:875, 0:1/3:20, 'cubic');`.

Comment: "I'm having trouble applying it" This error message could be a bit more specific. What fails exactly? What did you expect? Also instead of interp3 I often prefer griddedInterpolant or scatteredInterpolant.